# 3 cpus in idle state and CPU4 50~100% usage

Tags: 16.04

I dont know how to identify what is destroying my CPU4.
I cant find the process to kill.

[image]

I try to interrupt somethings related to a search in Google, but not working (gpe50 and sci).

How can I found the problem?
Thanks!

**If you need more information, tell me please**

Comment: This is not unusual behavior in systems, and to be honest you do not need to be worried about processes using a single processor more than others.  CPU4 is just one core inside your 4-core CPU system, and that isn't indicative of 'destroying' a CPU.  If your load average goes over 4 then you need to be more concerned.

Comment: The process is Firefox. One of the open sites is causing the use in CPU. Close your tabs one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing here is just a single-thread process running as fast as possible, with no pauses for user or storage inputs, no sleep cycles, etc.

This isn't unusual, at least for short times, and won't harm your CPU (Ubuntu will automatically throttle the clock speed as needed to keep core temperatures within limits, even if speeding up the cooling fan doesn't do the job).  If this behavior persists for more than a few minutes, you might have a script on an open web page that's in a loop (due to a bug, usually), or a process that's performing a relatively long-running task (I get this all the time for all eight of my cores because I run BOINC tasks).

Still, it won't harm the machine.

Comment: but for me, this process persist all the time with not pause, is constantly 50~100%.

Comment: Look at the top line of your `htop` -- that shows the process that's taking 38+% is firefox.  The second line shows `lightdm` with 17+%; that's 55% for just those two.

Comment: Yes but if I press the key SUPER/WIN 5 times for example, the desktop entire freeze. If I move windows fast, freeze, If I type fast, freeze.

Comment: I don't have answers for those latter problems -- they sound like a load balancing failure, but I don't know enough bout the under-hood workings to suggest where to look for fix.